# How to play a short audio file with CoreMotion and AVAudioPlayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, core-motion

I'm trying to play short sounds (1 to 4 seconds) when I move the iPhone on the X axis (I'm using `CoreMotion` and `AVAudioPlayer`). I want to play one sound for each movement direction change.

I wrote the code below, but when I move the iPhone, the sound is played many times without the movement direction change. The `print` calls below show many `Down` and `Up` such as `Down Down Down Up Down Down Up Up...`. If I comment both `play` callbacks, the `print` shows the alternation that I expect: `Down Up Down Up Down Up...`.

Why the `AVAudioPlayer.play` is called more than one time when the movement direction changes?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Audio
    audioURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("shortSound", withExtension: "wav")!
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioURL)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    } catch {
        print("audioPlayer failure")
    }

    // Sensor
    lastDirection = 0
    threshold = 2.1

    motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable {
        let queue = NSOperationQueue()
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(queue, withHandler: {
            data, error in

            guard let data = data else{
                return
            }

            // Get the acceleration
            let xAccel = data.acceleration.x
            let xPositive = xAccel > 0

            // Run if the acceleration is higher than theshold
            if abs(xAccel) > self.threshold {

                // Run only if the direction is changed
                if self.lastDirection != 1 && xPositive {
                    print("Up")
                    self.play() 
                    self.lastDirection = 1
                } else if self.lastDirection != -1 && !xPositive {
                    print("Down")
                    self.play()
                    self.lastDirection = -1
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func play() {
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a threading problem. You are running the updates on a background queue (`queue`, an arbitrary NSOperationQueue, which by the way you are also failing to retain), but then you are talking to `self.lastDirection` and calling `self.play()` on that same background queue without regard to the thread-safety of those activities.

I would suggest at the very least rewriting this section:

```
            if self.lastDirection != 1 && xPositive {
                print("Up")
                self.play() 
                self.lastDirection = 1
            } else if self.lastDirection != -1 && !xPositive {
                print("Down")
                self.play()
                self.lastDirection = -1
            }
```

...more like this:

```
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               if self.lastDirection != 1 && xPositive {
                    self.lastDirection = 1
                    print("Up")
                    self.play() 
                } else if self.lastDirection != -1 && !xPositive {
                    self.lastDirection = -1
                    print("Down")
                    self.play()
                }
            }
```

Note that I've made two changes: I've stepped out to the main thread for the entire check-print-play-toggle dance, and I've reversed the order of events so that it goes check-toggle-print-play.

Also I would suggest two other changes: retain the operation queue (i.e. make it a property instead of a local), and reduce the frequency of motion manager updates (by setting a lower `accelerometerUpdateInterval`).